# Do multiple residents compete for resources (fruit, fossils)?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm playing on someone else's 3DS where he is the Mayor and I am just a resident. We are both concerned that because we are both gathering fruit, digging up fossils, etc., that it'll lessen what the other person will have to collect. Does anyone know how often fruit, fossils spawn and whether that is increased if there are multiple players on the same cartridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. Fruit respawns after every few days. Fossils pop up every day. If you shake trees and dig up some fossils, there will be less for the mayor to collect...

Comment: Yup, you're sharing a town anything one person does affects the other.  If you're really concerned then you can just help each other out by mailing bells from one person to another.

Comment: This is true of fruit and fossils, but isn't true of the bell rock - each player gets their own. I don't know about other resources yet (gem rock, furniture trees).